# Can't install Resharper C++ into Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I install Resharper C++ into my Visual studio,the program failed like this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8mTo.png)

And I check the logfile the main 5 problem is like below

```
16:14:22.364 |E| IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineAssemblies| Could not read object from substorage “SimpleFileItem@JetBrains.Util.Storage 37”. Cannot bind the written object name “JetBrains.Util.Storage.SimpleFileItem, JetBrains.Platform.Util, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” to the type name.

--- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
Message = “Could not read object from substorage “SimpleFileItem@JetBrains.Util.Storage 37”. Cannot bind the written object name “JetBrains.Util.Storage.SimpleFileItem, JetBrains.Platform.Util, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” to the type name.”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  Could not read object from substorage “SimpleFileItem@JetBrains.Util.Storage 37”. Cannot bind the written object name “JetBrains.Util.Storage.SimpleFileItem, JetBrains.Platform.Util, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” to the type name.

  --- EXCEPTION #1/3 [NullReferenceException]
  Message = “Cannot bind the written object name “JetBrains.Util.Storage.SimpleFileItem, JetBrains.Platform.Util, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” to the type name.”
  ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException
  ClassName = System.NullReferenceException
  HResult = E_POINTER=COR_E_NULLREFERENCE=80004003
  Source = JetBrains.Platform.BuildInterfaces
  StackTraceString = “ JetBrains.Build.Serialization.StructuredStorageSerialization.ReadObjectsCollection[TObject](IStructuredStorage storage, OnError onerror, IBindTypeByName typebinder)”

  --- Outer ---

  --- EXCEPTION #2/3 [BuildException]
  Message = “Could not read object from substorage “SimpleFileItem@JetBrains.Util.Storage 37”.”
  ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
  ClassName = JetBrains.Build.BuildException
  InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException.InnerException”
  HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600

  --- Outer ---

  --- EXCEPTION #3/3 [LoggerException]
  Message = “Could not read object from substorage “SimpleFileItem@JetBrains.Util.Storage 37”.”
  ExceptionPath = Root
  ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
  InnerException = “Exception #2 at Root.InnerException”
  HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
  StackTraceString = “
     JetBrains.Util.OnError.<>c__DisplayClass7.<LogAlgorithmError>b__6(Exception ex)
        JetBrains.Util.OnError.Handle(Exception ex)
        JetBrains.Build.Serialization.StructuredStorageSerialization.ReadObjectsCollection[TObject](IStructuredStorage storage, OnError onerror, IBindTypeByName typebinder)
        JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineAssemblies..ctor(IStructuredStorage sstg)
        System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
        System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
        JetBrains.Build.Serialization.StructuredStorageSerialization.ReadObjectValue(Type type, IStructuredStorage storageValue, OnError onerror, IBindTypeByName typebinder)
       JetBrains.Build.Serialization.StructuredStorageSerialization.ReadObjectValue[TInstance](IStructuredStorage storageValue, OnError onerror, IBindTypeByName typebinder)
        JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuest.<>c__DisplayClass7.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Run>b__2()
        System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
        System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
        System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
        JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineAssemblies.ChosenEngine.GetOwner()
        JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineAssemblies.ChosenEngine.GetChosenEngineFilesOnly()
       JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.ScriptSources.ScriptSourceImplicitEngineDllReferences.CreateFromEngine_GetAssemblyAndReferences(AssemblyNameInfo assemblyStart, ChosenEngine enginefiles, ILogger Logger)
       JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.ScriptSources.ScriptSourceImplicitEngineDllReferences.CreateFromEngine(ChosenEngine enginefiles, ILogger Logger)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.ScriptSources.ScriptSourceImplicitEngineDllReferences.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetMetadataReferences>b__0()
       在 JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch[TValue](ILogger thіs, Func`1 F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.ScriptSources.ScriptSourceImplicitEngineDllReferences.GetMetadataReferences(ILogger Logger)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuestCatalog.ScriptFromInputs(IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineRequest request, Optional`1 environment, ChosenEngine enginefiles, ILogger Logger)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuestCatalog.CreateBuildCatalog(Lifetime lifetime, IsolatedBuildRunnerEngineRequest request, IRealizedAssemblyItemUnification realizedAssemblyItemUnification, Optional`1 environment, ChosenEngine enginefiles, ILogger Logger)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuest.<>c__DisplayClass7.<Run>b__0(Lifetime lifetime)
       在 JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Using[TRetVal](Func`2 λ)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuest.Run(IntPtr pCrossAppDomain)
       在 JetBrains.Build.Engine.IsolatedBuild.IsolatedBuildGuest..ctor(IntPtr pCrossAppDomain)
       在 System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       在 System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       在 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       在 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
       在 System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       在 System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
       在 System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
  ”
”

16:14:22.681 |E| InstallerService              | There is no component of type “JetBrains.Application.Install.InstallationData.InstallationDataFinal, JetBrains.Platform.Shell, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” among the serialized values.

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = “There is no component of type “JetBrains.Application.Install.InstallationData.InstallationDataFinal, JetBrains.Platform.Shell, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” among the serialized values.”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = JetBrains.Platform.BuildInterfaces
StackTraceString = “
  在 JetBrains.Build.Serialization.SerializedValuesResolver.Resolve(Type type)
     在 JetBrains.Build.Serialization.SerializedValuesResolver.Resolve[TComponent]()
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClassbc.<RunRegisterScript>b__b6()
     在 JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch[TValue](ILogger thіs, Func`1 F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “There is no component of type “JetBrains.Application.Install.InstallationData.InstallationDataFinal, JetBrains.Platform.Shell, Version=109.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325” among the serialized values.”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  在 JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch[TValue](ILogger thіs, Func`1 F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.RunRegisterScript(Lifetime lifetime, BuildRunnerRequest request, IIsolatedBuildRunners runners, IProgressIndicator pi)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<RegisterVsHost>b__1d(Lifetime lifetime)
     在 JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Using[TRetVal](Func`2 λ)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.RegisterVsHost(InstallableHost installableHost, LocalPaths localPaths, InstallablePackages packages, IIsolatedBuildRunners runners, IProgressIndicator pi, FileSystemPath folder, Boolean ignoreExtensions, Boolean perMachine)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClass18.<RegisterHost>b__15(Lifetime lifetime)
     在 JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Using(Action`1 λ)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.RegisterHost(IIsolatedBuildRunners runners, InstallableHostInFolder hostInFolder, InstallerContext context, Boolean ignoreExtensions, IProgressIndicator pi)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InstallHosts>b__9()
     在 JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch(ILogger thіs, Action F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.InstallHosts(IIsolatedBuildRunners runners, InstallableHostInFolder[] hostsToUpdate, InstallerContext context, Boolean ignoreExtensions, IProgressOwner owner, IProgressIndicator pi)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<>c__DisplayClass7.<Install>b__3(Lifetime lifetimeUnsync)
     在 JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Using(Action`1 λ)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Install>b__2()
     在 JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Catch(ILogger thіs, Action F, ExceptionOrigin origin, LoggingLevel loggingLevel)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Services.InstallerService.Install(InstallTargets targets, InstallerContext context, InstalledProductsDiscovery productsDiscovery, IProgressOwner owner, Boolean ignoreExtensions)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Models.InstallerViewModel.<GoInstall>b__31(InstallTargets targets, IProgressOwner progress)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Models.ReadyToInstallPage.<GoInstall>b__30(Lifetime lifetime, IProgressOwner owner)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Models.InstallerPageWithProgress.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RunAction>b__3()
     在 JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Models.InstallerPageWithProgress.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RunAction>b__2()
     在 JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
     在 JetBrains.Platform.Installer.Models.InstallerPageWithProgress.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RunAction>b__1()
     在 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     在 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     在 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     在 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     在 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
”
```

I tried to google it but there is no result.I wonder if I'm not use the correct key words to search this problem.I tried to use the privilege mode but it is not work.However, I can install the original Resharper successfully. So how can I do to install the Resharper C++?

Comment: Could you please create a topic in the ReSharper support forum (https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community) and attach the installation log there? ReSharper's support team will help you with the error.

Comment: It looks like you are using a web installer to install ReSharper C++. Try downloading a full one from https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download, run it, select 'Install' for ReSharper C++ tool only and proceed the installation.

Comment: @Alexander Kurakin yeah,it fixed my problem,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a web installer to install ReSharper C++. Download a full one from jetbrains.com/resharper/download, run it, select 'Install' for ReSharper C++ tool only and proceed the installation